# How to convert keys from upper case to lower case instantly in richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert upper keys to lower keys instantly while typing in richtextbox.

Tried following:
`If Char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar) Then Char.ToLower(e.KeyChar)`

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    If CType(e, KeyPressEventArgs).KeyChar = vbCr Then
        Search()
    End If
    If Char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar) Then Char.ToLower(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Obviously not working.

Comment: Are you actually using the `RichTextBox` to display RTF data?  So many people don't and should just be using a `TextBox` instead.  In that case you can just set the `CharacterCasing` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

First you need to alter the function header to use a more specific version of the `KeyPressEventArgs` rather than the generic `EventArgs`

Change the eventhandler to be:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
```

Once this is done, you get access to a different set of properties for the `KeyPress` event.

This `Char.ToLower` is a function that returns a value. Do:

```
If Char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar) Then e.KeyChar = Char.ToLower(e.KeyChar)
```

you need to add `e.KeyChar =` to the Left Hand Side of the function to store the result.